# Get a file from a plugin in Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-365

I´ve installed Dynamics Version 1612 (8.2.2.112) (DB 8.2.2.112) on-premises. I wrote a plugin to connect to a web API, work perfect, now I need to add more situations. The API can return an url to a zipped file with the response in a JSON file. Well, there're any change to point me in the right direction? First, to get the file. STFW so far he gave me no clue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question about Dynamics specifically or just how to download a file from a URL in C#? Perhaps you should try a different search - https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+download+file+from+url

Comment: @Jeff Dynamics, and the file is a tar.gz with a JSON file inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an URL then get unzip and process.

Example how to get and unzip file.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData("URL")))
{
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
       ...
    }
}
```